# Images loading in the DOM after JS runs

Tags: javascript, image, src

Real strange problem I'm having. I have this simple guessing game that asks four questions. It takes user input with an alert, prints to the DOM whether the user guessed correctly or incorrectly, and then displays an image (green checkbox or red x), THEN moves onto the next question.
And so on, and so forth.

PROBLEM:
The game runs, prints the message to the DOM, but does not show the images until the entire game is over.

What is strange is that the chrome console clearly shows that the "src" attribute of the img elements are being modified properly (and the file tree is correctly arranged to access the images).
Instead, a blank box shows up. Until the end of the game, of course.

Sample of what my HTML looks like:

```
<p id="question1" class="rightAnswer" class="wrongAnswer"></p>
<img id="img1" src="" width="100">
```

JS functions (IIFE's). There's one function for each question and they all look identical to this one:

```
var question1 = (function() {
  var userAnswer1 = prompt(arrayQuestions[0]);
  if((userAnswer1.toUpperCase() === "BOSTON") || (userAnswer1.toUpperCase() === "BOS")) {
    // inserts correct or incorrect message after user guesses
    document.getElementById('question1').innerHTML= arrayAnswerCorrect[0];
    // changes color of that message
    document.getElementById('question1').style.color = "green";
    // inserts image via 'src' attribute
    document.getElementById('img1').src = "images/correct.png";

    scoreIt++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('question1').innerHTML = arrayAnswerIncorrect[0];
    document.getElementById('question1').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('img1').src = "images/incorrect.png";
  };
}());
```

Thank you in advance. This is really stumping me.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or a codepen pls?

Comment: Yep! I'll get on that. One minute.

Comment: Hmmm... I think because this involves alerts it's making the JSFiddle freak out... Anyway, here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/josectello/tky6y0bt/

Comment: that's incorrect because js is executing only image.src change isn't reflecting in view

Comment: ok so firefox and chrome execute the innerHTML change but not load the image, safari everything is blocked till prompts finish

Comment: So you're saying that image.src will not actually make the image show up in the DOM? If so, then what is the proper way?

Comment: Jose, proper way is that the whole prompt strategy, one prompt after the other is not cross browser compatible, you should consider doing this in a custom js/css3 modal

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that... I wouldn't do it this way normally, but the assignment requires use of alerts. I dislike alerts altogether, but it's not my choice.

Comment: does your assignment say native javascript alerts and prohibits the use of custom jquery modal alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions and DOM updates are in single block of code that starts, asks questions one at a time, and finally completes execution after the last question.

But javascript threads run to completion: once started nothing interrupts them until the code returns. Prompts just block the javascript thread until the user enters the information. Although browsers accept modifications to the DOM during an execution thread, and may reflect changes to the DOM back in DOM element attributes, they generally defer re-rendering the page until the script has finished.

You will need to rethink how to ask the questions in order but run the code for each question to completion before starting the next one. Two possibilities are obvious: 1) The "next question" button, and 2) looking into using a `setTimeout` call to call the next question code.  good luck ;-)